# How do you get the count of dead letter messages in an Azure Service Bus queue?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

How do you get the count of dead letter messages in an Azure Service Bus queue?

I can get the count in the queue like so ...

```
var ns = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(sbConnectionString);
var queue = ns.GetQueue(queueName);
var count = queue.MessageCount;
```

But this looks to include both messages in the queue, and also messages in the associated dead letter queue

How can I differentiate between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do take a look at [`MessageCountDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagecountdetails) property in [`QueueDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueDescription_MessageCountDetails). You will find [`DeadletterMessageCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagecountdetails#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessageCountDetails_DeadLetterMessageCount) there which will provide you the information you're looking for.

```
var ns = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(sbConnectionString);
var queue = ns.GetQueue(queueName);
var count = queue.MessageCount;
var deadletterMessagesCount = queue.MessageCountDetails.DeadletterMessageCount;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid answer anymore. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus namespace doesn't have NamespaceManager object but ManagementClient and no MessageCount properties. Using Azure Service Bus Metrics is recomended instead: https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/reading-azure-service-bus-metrics