# Monitoring Azure Service Bus Queue Depth from ASP.NET Core 2.0 Console App

Tags: c#, .net-core, azureservicebus

I am trying to monitor both total queue depth and DeadLetterMessages queue depth from an ASP.NET Core 2.0 console application. I have seen references to using the NamespaceManager class, something like this:

```
var ns = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(sbConnectionString);
var queue = ns.GetQueue(queueName);
var count = queue.MessageCount;
var deadletterMessagesCount = queue.MessageCountDetails.DeadletterMessageCount;
```

(from [How do you get the count of dead letter messages in an Azure Service Bus queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932926/how-do-you-get-the-count-of-dead-letter-messages-in-an-azure-service-bus-queue))

but the NamespaceManager is in Microsoft.ServiceBus, which is not compatible with ASP.NET Core.

Any suggestions on how to get the message count?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the equivalent of NamespaceManager.GetQueue.MessageCount in the new NET Standard Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191650/whats-the-equivalent-of-namespacemanager-getqueue-messagecount-in-the-new-net-s)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration` namespace in the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` library.

Setup a new administration client like this:

```
var client = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient("connectionstring");
```

Then get the message count/depth like so:

```
        var queuesRuntimeProperties = client.GetQueuesRuntimePropertiesAsync().AsPages();
        await foreach (var queuePage in queuesRuntimeProperties)
        {
            foreach (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.QueueRuntimeProperties currentQueue in queuePage.Values)
            {
                dict.Add(currentQueue.Name, currentQueue.TotalMessageCount.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

> Any suggestions on how to get the message count?

As Mikhail mentioned that it is **not supporte**d to that with Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus currently.

If you want to get the message count with Azure SDK on the .net core platform, I recommand that you could use the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent) to do that.

The following is the demo code.

```
 //auth file:c:\tom\azureCredential.txt
 var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"c:\tom\azureCredential.txt"); 
 var azure = Azure
             .Configure()
             .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
             .Authenticate(credentials)
             .WithDefaultSubscription();

 var serviceBus = azure.ServiceBusNamespaces.GetByResourceGroup("Resource group name", "servicebus namespace");
 var queue = serviceBus.Queues.GetByName("queueName");
 var activeMessageCount = queue.ActiveMessageCount;
 var deadletterCount = queue.DeadLetterMessageCount;
```

**Note:** `queue.MessageCount` is the number all of the message including the DeadLetterMessage.

How to [create an Azure Active Directory application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application) and [assign application to role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).

How to create the auth file please refer to [auth file formats](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md#auth-file-formats)

```
subscription=########-####-####-####-############
client=########-####-####-####-############
tenant=########-####-####-####-############
key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
managementURI=https\://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https\://management.azure.com/
authURL=https\://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https\://graph.windows.net/
```

Test result:

[image]